# Scrolling large image inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an large image inside a small div. Inside that div there are 4 arrows to control the movement, right, bottom, left and top. The arrows are used to move the image inside that smaller div.

This is the JS code

```
$('.slide-right').click(function() {
    $('.inner img').animate({ "right": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
});
$('.slide-bottom').click(function() {
    $('.inner img').animate({ "bottom": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
});
$('.slide-left').click(function() {
    $('.inner img').animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
});
$('.slide-top').click(function() {
    $('.inner img').animate({ "top": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
});
```

And this is the html:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="image-box">
        <div class="inner"><img alt="" src="http://s15.postimg.org/5phzr2off/img.jpg" id="image" /></div>
        <div id="arrow-up"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slide-top"><img alt="" src="http://s24.postimg.org/gr2uv14d1/arrow_top.png" /></a></div>
        <div id="arrow-right"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slide-right"><img alt="" src="http://s24.postimg.org/ruda95avp/arrow_right.png" /></a></div>
        <div id="arrow-bottom"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slide-bottom"><img alt="" src="http://s10.postimg.org/n8hv0166x/arrow_bottom.png" /></a></div>
        <div id="arrow-left"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slide-left"><img alt="" src="http://s2.postimg.org/qrpm662u1/arrow_left.png" /></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/john_bale96/C26rV/

I would like to make the animation to stop when the edge of the image is reached. Can someone give me some clues on how to do this ?

Comment: Not the complete solution but it may help [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f00bar/C26rV/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't change all 4 `top` `right` `bottom` `left`, as you'll end up with stuff like `right:1000px; left:1000px;` etc... and it'll probably break the thing.

Focus on using just 2 of them instead, i'd recommend just using `top` and `left`

So to go right, you'd do `left += 50px` to go left you'd do `left -= 50px`

A simple way to resolve this solution would be to simply manually plot the contraints like this:

```
$('.slide-right').click(function() {      
    if (parseInt($('.inner img').css('left')) >= -700) {
        $('.inner img').finish().animate({ "left": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
    }
});

$('.slide-bottom').click(function() {
    if (parseInt($('.inner img').css('top')) >= -249) {
        $('.inner img').finish().animate({ "top": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
    }
});

$('.slide-left').click(function() {
    if (parseInt($('.inner img').css('left')) < -49) {
        $('.inner img').finish().animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
    }
});

$('.slide-top').click(function() {
    if (parseInt($('.inner img').css('top')) < -49) {
        $('.inner img').finish().animate({ "top": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C26rV/4/

But ideally you could do something better which would determine the dimensions of the image itself allowing it to work with any image size automatically.

**Edit:**

Just as a side note (It doesn't have constraints) you can use considerably less jQuery by handling sliding like this:

```
$('.slide').click(function () {
    var sliding = {}
    sliding[$(this).data('direction')] = $(this).data('movement');
    $('.inner img').animate(sliding,"slow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C26rV/2/

Comment: Note that if you don't unbind the events while animating, you can still move the image outside of the constraints; try clicking on right once, then click on left three times (fast)

Comment: @lhoeppner My preference would be just to use `finish()` http://jsfiddle.net/C26rV/4/

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider that, at the beginning, your image is `left:0px` and `top:0px`.
So you already have your left and top limite.

```
$('.slide-left').click(function () {
    if ($('.inner img').position().left + 50 < 0) {
        $('.inner img').animate({
            "left": "+=50px"
        }, "slow");
    } 
});

$('.slide-top').click(function () {
    if ($('.inner img').position().top + 50 < 0) {
        $('.inner img').animate({
            "top": "+=50px"
        }, "slow");
    } 
});
```

Then, you can get the right and bottom limite. This is your image size.

```
var limiteRight = 0 - $('.inner img').width() + $('.image-box').width();
var limiteBottom = 0 - $('.inner img').height() + $('.image-box').height();


$('.slide-right').click(function () {
    if ($('.inner img').position().left - 50 > limiteRight) {
        $('.inner img').animate({
            "left": "-=50px"
        }, "slow");
    }
});

$('.slide-bottom').click(function () {
    if ($('.inner img').position().top - 50 > limiteBottom) {
        $('.inner img').animate({
            "top": "-=50px"
        }, "slow");
    }
});
```

And you finnaly have to check if your desired new position is within this container. If not, just go to the limite.

```
$('.slide-right').click(function () {
    if ($('.inner img').position().left - 50 > limiteRight) {
        $('.inner img').animate({
            "left": "-=50px"
        }, "slow");
    } else {
        $('.inner img').animate({
            "left": limiteRight
        }, "slow");
    }
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QaTDG/)** with full exemple.

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach would be to compare the image position with the containing div position:

```
    var inner = $(".inner").first();
    var divTop = inner.offset().top;
    var divLeft = inner.offset().left;
    var divRight = divLeft + inner.width();
    var divBottom = divTop + inner.height();

    function getImagePosition() {
        var image = $("#image");
        var imageTop = image.offset().top;
        var imageLeft = image.offset().left;

        return {
            top: imageTop,
            left: imageLeft,
            right: imageLeft + image.width(),
            bottom: imageTop + image.height()
        }
    }

    function scrollTop() {
        var imagePosition = getImagePosition();

        var nextImageTop = imagePosition.top + 50;
        if (nextImageTop <= divTop) {
            $('.slide-top').off("click");

            $('.inner img').animate({
                "top": "+=50px"
            }, "slow", function () {
                $('.slide-top').click(scrollTop);
            });
        }
    }

    $('.slide-top').click(scrollTop);
```

You should also unbind the arrow scrolling events while the animation happens, otherwise if the user clicks multiple times while the animation is happening, it can still scroll the image outside of the div constraints.

See this fiddle (I only implemented the rebinding for top):

http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/puLDd/

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion, using jQuery UI draggable.

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

http://jsfiddle.net/kimgysen/3twxS/1/

```
$("#inner").draggable({
    containment: $('#content')
});
```

Comment: Yup, if you can use jQuery UI, this is much easier, of course.

Comment: I thought this may be easier; I thought about how Facebook uses a similar dragging action for panning the cover picture in the containing div...

Comment: Ah. Not using Facebook bites me in the ass again! :)