# View a part of the image, and be allowed to view other parts of the image with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, scroll

I have been struggling to write a program to view 500x1000 of an image that is 7960x8264. You can move your view with the W,S,A,and D keys. I am aware of the CSS clip function, and I've tried using JS to modify it. Nothing seems to work, and I've spent so much time on it, so I really need a person with experience to help out. I've done the following code:

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449618/scrolling-large-image-inside-a-div) stackoverflow post, but I am struggling to reimplement it.

```js
    window.onkeypress = function(event) {
       if (event.keyCode == 115) {
          document.getElementById("container").style.clip = "rect(0px,5000px,5000px,0px)"; //this is supposed to change what part you see (the 'focus/view'), but it will actually move the view up in thw final program.
       }
       if (event.keyCode == 119) {
          //move the view up
       }
       if (event.keyCode == 97) {
          //move the view left
       }
       if (event.keyCode == 100) {
          //move the view right
       }
    }
```

```css
 #clip {
    }
```

```html
index.html:

      <div id="container">
        <img src="img/game_resources/background/sky.jpg" />
      </div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you could try putting it in an `svg` tag so that you can use the `viewbox` attribute to set what would be shown (e.g. `viewbox="0 0 500 1000` where x and y are the coordinates of the top left corner of the image and then use `element.setAttribute("viewbox") = x + " " + y + " 500 1000"` in your JavaScript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clip property you're trying to use will leave the image in its original location, and will only change what part is visible. Also, for clip to work, the element must have either `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`.

The more traditional css approach for a moving background or skybox would be giving the container a fixed size and using a background image instead of an `<img />`. You can then move the image around with javascript using the `background-position`. An example at https://jsfiddle.net/3s9rkn3x/

Alternatively, if you have to use an `<img />` tag, you can give your container an `overflow: hidden` to clip the image, and then position the image inside the container with `position: absolute;` and `top: yyypx`, `left: yyypx`.